# Possible bug (probably with X or video drivers) that doesn’t allow keyboard / mouse access at greeter

Tags: release-juno, xorg

I’m troubled. I messed something up, and don’t know how to fix it.
I was changing some X stuff (and some video driver stuff) and everything seemed to be working fine. Then, I rebooted, and I couldn’t login because my keyboard wasn’t typing, and my mouse wasn’t moving. Please note that when I typed, it made the cursor flash, like it would if you typed an invalid character. I can log in via single user, so I can enter commands via the console, and I ran `init 3` to get permissions.
I am stuck. I’ve been trying everything I could think of to fix it, to no avail, for about 5 hours. I really want my stuff back, without reinstalling. Could I please have some suggestions?

info follows

cat /etc/X11/Xsession.options returns (excluding commented lines)

```
allow-failsafe
allow-user-resources
allow-user-xsession 
use-ssh-agent 
use-session-dbus
```

.

cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager returns

```
/usr/sbin/lightdm
```

Tell me if you need other files.

Comment: I would like to know your situation more clear. Please [join this chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92413/talk-with-hasan)

Comment: Can you please update your status? Do you still have the problem?

Comment: I reinstalled (this time I went for Ubuntu) so I don’t have this problem.